# Is it right to close a question which can be seen as related to a tag if it doesn't match the description?

Tags: discussion, tags

I had posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75810361/is-there-a-way-to-separate-a-domain-into-parts-pointing-to-different-ip). I had added the tags [cloudflare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudflare) and [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns).

The other person said that the question doesn't match the description for the [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) tag, should be closed and is not allowed. I looked into the [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) tag description and I agree it doesn't match the description. So I removed the tag, but I don't think the question should be closed.

Comment: What the tag description is warning you is that questions that are not about programming are off-topic for the site, regardless of how they are tagged.

Comment: "So I removed the tag but I don't think the question should be closed." Why do you think so? The closure wasn't due to the tags, so just removing the tag does not remove the closure reason.

Comment: Your question isn't related to programming, so it's not on-topic here.  But it got a helpful answer, so I fixed it up a bit and [sent it over to Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1127496) for you, where I believe that it would be on-topic.

Comment: So if i get it right stack overflow is for programming related question. 
What got me confused is he mentioned the dns tag description and said he was closing it. So i thought why close it when it doesn't match one tag since it matches cloudflare tag.

Adding the warning in a tag doesn't make sense it should added overall in the site i think. 

Well thanks everyone got it

Comment: It's because people can apply the reasoning "There's a DNS tag; that means that DNS questions are appropriate for the site." The tag description is telling you that only some categories of such questions are appropriate for the site.

Comment: If thats the case there is cloudflare tag so the question should be appropriate for the site right?

Comment: The definition of on-topic is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - even if a tag exists, every question needs to meet the requirements there.

Comment: @Origin Your reasoning that "there is X tag so the question should be appropriate" is exactly why many tags have an extra reminder that not *everything* about X is on-topic. However, these are *manually* added *reminders* – even if they are missing, the general site rules still apply.

Comment: I understand i just got confused because of the reason he specified in that stack overflow question. 
The link from Ryan  stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic makes it clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If a question has an incorrect tag, but is otherwise fine, the tag should simply be removed/replaced. If fitting, a comment could be added why that tag shouldn't be used in this context.

In your case, your question as a whole is more about about administrating and would be more fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour). As per said site:

> Server Fault is a question and answer site for system and network administrators.